# flash player not working in 13.04

Tags: installation

Just installed 13.04. It say that version Flash Player 11.2 is installed, but I can't get it to work.

Anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: Can you tell us what you are trying to run and in which programme?

Answer (score 0):

try updating all packages

update software list :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

upgrade softwares :

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

to update specific program :

```
sudo apt-get install (package)
```